# DatePicker CalendarView

Tags: android, calendarview

I can't seem to find this, is there a way to show a calendar where you can pick your date instead of the 3 column datepicker widget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Android 3.0, there is a `CalendarView` widget you can use.

On other versions of Android, there is nothing built in for this.

Once the source code to Android 3.0 is released, you can look at perhaps cloning `CalendarView` for use in your pre-3.0 apps.